# How to get the last hierarchy child

Tags: jquery

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oneng/rFA7N/2/)

Need make **< a >** tag in very last level **< li >** linkible

For all **< a >** not in last **< li >** level == **event.preventDefault(e);**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="">ul li</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">ul li ul li</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">ul li ul li ul li last click true</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">ul li</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">ul li ul li last click true</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">ul li</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">ul li ul li</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">ul li ul li ul li</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">ul li ul li ul li ul li last click true</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

fixes question:
I mean last level **< li >** tag...

Comment: What does "last hierarchy child" mean?

Comment: Congrats, you have earned the "Confusing" badge.

Comment: I mean last level tag li

Comment: Nested anchor tags are illegal HTML. Fix that first and perhaps the answer to the question will be simpler.

Comment: @Jon there are no nested anchors here.... it was just badly formatted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One logic I can see is if the `a` has a `ul` sibling then prevent the default action

```
jQuery('a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).next('ul').length != 0
}).click(function (e) {
    event.preventDefault(e);
    jQuery(this).next('ul').animate({height:"toggle", opacity:"toggle"}, 300);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4vZZD/)

Comment: .next() is for siblings, looks like OP is looking for children instead even the question is not really clear

Comment: @A.Wolff the `a` does not have children... the parent `li` has both `a` and `ul` elements.. so they are siblings... did I miss anything

Comment: No, sorry, looks like I miss something! ;)

Comment: Yes, this is what i mean!